# sudo stdbuf -o0 VS stdbuf -o0 sudo, and the scope of redirection

Tags: bash, shell

Hi I was running the following command and realize the someone of the output's log is missing

```
root@janux-spr1:/home/tw12/redis_research/dpdk-framework/dpdk-rx# { sudo ./dpdk-rx -l 3-5 -a 0000:18:00.1 -- -m 0 -d 0 -l 1 -i 500; } &> test.log; cat test.log

EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 32
EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 1
EAL: Detected shared linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci (15b3:101b) device: 0000:18:00.1 (socket 0)
mlx5_common: DevX read access NIC register=0X9055 failed errno=121 status=0x3 syndrome=0x54e3a9
TELEMETRY: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
Floating point exception
```

Then I realize that it might be a buffering issue so I add stdbuf to close stdout buffer, but I was surprise to see the location of stdbuf actually matter. The following command is after I add the stdbuf. The second one shows all the log I needed

```
root@janux-spr1:/home/tw12/redis_research/dpdk-framework/dpdk-rx# { stdbuf -o0 sudo ./dpdk-rx -l 3-5 -a 0000:18:00.1 -- -m 0 -d 0 -l 1 -i 500; } &> test.log; cat test.log
EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 32
EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 1
EAL: Detected shared linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci (15b3:101b) device: 0000:18:00.1 (socket 0)
mlx5_common: DevX read access NIC register=0X9055 failed errno=121 status=0x3 syndrome=0x54e3a9
TELEMETRY: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
Floating point exception
```

```
root@janux-spr1:/home/tw12/redis_research/dpdk-framework/dpdk-rx# { sudo stdbuf -o0 ./dpdk-rx -l 3-5 -a 0000:18:00.1 -- -m 0 -d 0 -l 1 -i 500; } &> test.log; cat test.log
EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 32
EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 1
EAL: Detected shared linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci (15b3:101b) device: 0000:18:00.1 (socket 0)
mlx5_common: DevX read access NIC register=0X9055 failed errno=121 status=0x3 syndrome=0x54e3a9
TELEMETRY: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
5 EAL arguments used
0 application arguments used
================ Configuration ================
Port:           0
Interval:       500 msec
Packet Rate:    N/A (no rate limiting)
===============================================
RX lcore count: 3
Allocated mbuf pool size 71303168B
Init port 0
PCI address: 0000:18:00.1
Set up 2 TX rings (4096 descriptors per ring)
Set up 2 RX rings (4096 descriptors per ring)
Port 0 MAC: b8 3f d2 59 5f e1
CPU running in 2000 MHz, printing interval is 500ms -- 1000000000 cycles
Starting RX Threads -- Main thread NOT treats as RX thread
lcore  4 (lcore index  1, RX index  0) starts to receive packets
lcore  5 (lcore index  2, RX index  1) starts to receive packets
Floating point exception
```

Two more general question to ask are:

1. what is the scope of redirection. Will redirection and buffer setting only work on the particular command it attach to? If yes, what if the command is built with several subcommand inside, like "sudo time XXX", or "bash -c '' "
2. Also.. for `sudo time XXX > logfile`, will XXX be redirected, or the entire `sudo time XXX`?
   Similar question as `command1 && command2 > logfile && command3`, `{command1 && command2} > logfile`, etc

If possible where could I learn more about these thing... I have been digging bash learning material for long time but still get highly confused by these thing

I did checked the word spliting but I still don't get how bash indentify if a certain word is a command by itself, or a argument to its previous command

Comment: Please reduce your PS1 prompt size so your actual command is visible without having to scroll right. `#` by itself is recognized as the `root` users prompt.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general answer. Every case if unique.

In the case of `sudo`, it does not pass environment variables to child processes. See `man sudo` option `--preserve-env`.

> what is the scope of redirection

Bash sets up the redirection, i.e. associated the file with the file descriptor, and then runs processes. The file descriptors are inherited for child processes. See `man 2 fork` and `man 2 clone` and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor .

> Will redirection setting only work on the particular command it attach to?

No. It will also be inherited by all child processes, as long as the parent does not close the redirection before `fork`ing.

> Will buffer setting only work on the particular command it attach to?

No. The interpretation is that "buffer setting" is what `setbuf` does.

All `setbuf` does is set `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable to a library `libsetbuf.so` and then spawns the child process. The `libsetbuf.so` all does is execute `setvbuf()` on process startup. See `man 3 setvbuf`, `man 1 setbuf`, `man 3 setbuf`, `man ld.so` and https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Controlling-Buffering.html and https://github.com/wertarbyte/coreutils/blob/f70c7b785b93dd436788d34827b209453157a6f2/src/stdbuf.c#L189-L250 ,

On process startup, the [dynamic linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) `ld.so` (see `man ld.so`) loads the libraries mentioned from `LD_PRELOAD`. All processes that inherit the environment and will have `LD_PRELOAD` set to `libstdbuf.so` library will have the `libstdbuf.so` loaded on startup, and so will inherit the "buffer setting".

> If yes, what if the command is built with several subcommand inside, like "sudo time XXX", or "bash -c '' "

Then it totally depends on what flags will the processes pass to `clone()` system call. Each process may pass different variables to the child process and modify the environment. In case of `bash`, `bash` does not modify the environment, so everything is inherited. In the case of `sudo` there is a huge configuration in `sudoers`.

> for sudo time XXX > logfile, will XXX be redirected, or the entire sudo time XXX?

Both. The child processes spawned by `sudo` inherit the stdout file descriptors, but see `closefrom_override` option from `sudoers`, see `man 8 sudo`.

> Similar question as command1 && command2 > logfile && command3

Only `command2`.

> {command1 && command2} > logfile, etc

Both `command1` and `command2`.

You might be interested in shell syntax, in particular in command grouping https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html , command lists https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html and the whole section on redirections https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html .